# How do I get an uploaded image URL or the default for use in a template (code improvement)

Tags: 8, entities

I have a working preprocess function that allows me to grab an image for use as a background in the page template from a node if the field exists.  It falls back on a default image if supplied, the function looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_page() for page.html.twig.
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_page(array &$vars) {

  // Preprocess the hero image if it exists (it should on all nodes).
  if (isset($vars['node']->field_hero)){
    $field_hero = $vars['node']->get('field_hero')->getValue();

    // If a file has been uploaded, get it.
    if (!empty($field_hero)){
      $hero_id = $field_hero[0]['target_id'];
      $file = File::load($hero_id);

    // Otherwise get the default if there is one.
    } else {
      $default_image = $vars['node']->getFields()['field_hero']->getFieldDefinition()->getSetting('default_image');
      $file = Drupal::service('entity.repository')->loadEntityByUuid('file', $default_image['uuid']);
    }

    // If a file has been found (there might not be a default), get its path.
    if ($file){
      $path = $file->getFileUri();
      $vars['hero'] = ImageStyle::load('hero_image')->buildUrl($path);
    }
  }

}
```

Finding the default file is a convoluted mess of steps that requires loading all of the fields... there has got to be a better way to do this.  Is there?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to load all the fields, you can just load the image field:

```
$uuid = $vars['node']->get('field_hero')->getFieldDefinition()->getSetting('default_image')['uuid'];
$file = \Drupal::service('entity.manager')->loadEntityByUuid('file', $uuid);
```

On a different note, the first line of your code assumes that $vars['node'] exists, which it won't on non-node pages, so you should change it to:

```
if (isset($vars['node'], $vars['node']->field_hero))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Unfortunately there is no such method as `Node::getField`, and `$vars['node']->get('field_hero')` returns NULL if there's nothing in the field.  Error msg was  `PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Drupal\\node\\Entity\\Node::getField()`

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for typing without first checking. I just did a quick test and edited my code. You can use what I have got above to load the file entity.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but as I mentioned the equivalent of your code `$vars['node']->get('field_image_image')` returns nothing unless I've actually uploaded an image on the node.

Comment: It's working for me, so I don't know what to say. You didn't use field_image_image directly as-is did you? You need to replace that with field_hero like in your code.

Comment: Edited my code to use field_hero just in case.

Comment: I'll try again when I'm back at work =)